# Sorting the entries in the grid menu

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

In the [grid menu](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/121_grid_menu), the order of entries for the columns seem to be based on the order in which they were defined and not alphabetized. Is there a way to sort the entries so that it is easier for users to find the right column in tables with many columns?